# Upload svg file in pimcore

Tags: svg, assets, pimcore

Can I upload svg file in pimcore Assets ? I get this error:
[svg upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xe0W.png)

Comment: I encountered the same error.

Comment: The answer is Yes. but you need to install  Imagick on your server. Check System Requirements in pimcore admin.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! Thanks for taking the time to post back!